# Laravel how to return related model data using whereHas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have `Member` model `Ledger` model

```
class Member extends Model
{
    public function ledger()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Ledger','user_id');
    }
}
```

I have to get the ledger records of members (need both members and ledger data) where ledger.created_at = a particular date for example `ledger.created_at = 2017-03-26 14:15:26`

If I run the following script

```
 $members = Member::whereHas('ledger', function($q){
       $q->where('created_at', '2017-03-26 14:15:26');
 })->get();
```

I get only members data no ledger records.

If I run the following script

```
 $members =  Member::with(['ledger' => function($q) {
         $q->where('created_at', '2017-03-26 14:15:26');
     }])->where('type','=','5')->paginate(10);
```

I get the members with the required ledger records that is good, but it also returns other members where ledger records = null, I do not need the members  who do not have a ledger record. (ie I need only members where ledger.created = '2017-03-26 14:15:26 along with the ledger records)

How can I achieve this?

I am using Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use both `whereHas()` to filter members and `with()` to load `ledger` data:

```
$members = Member::whereHas('ledger', function($q) {
    $q->where('created_at', '2017-03-26 14:15:26');
})
->with(['ledger' => function($q) {
    $q->where('created_at', '2017-03-26 14:15:26');
}])
->where('type', 5)
->paginate(10);
```

Comment: That can be really slow

Comment: @peter if you know a faster Eloquent solution, please tell us about it. It's always good to have alternatives to be able to choose the best solution.